# Recording desk view on macOS Ventura

Tags: ventura, continuity

I'm trying to capture a video using macOS Ventura's "desk view" feature.

The desk view works well when I mount my iPhone on top of my laptop. However, when trying to capture a video using a recording app, it ignores the desk view and shows only the webcam frame. Even when desk view is enabled, I can only see the desk view viewfinder.

For instance, when trying to use QuickTime to capture video. I see myself from the iPhone camera at the preview but not the desk view perspective.

I thought of a workaround of turning the desk view preview window into full screen and then recording the screen. But I wonder if there's a more elegant way of achieving this.

Does anyone know how I can capture the desk view signal directly?